# Problem with find a specific part of XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am working with XML files and I want to have access in the author id and text of this file. I implement the following code but I am not sure for some lines.

```
for filepath in dataset_filepaths:

  with open(filepath) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")
  body = soup.body

  # To choose the author id !!! Is not working
  author = body.select('author_id')[0].get_text().strip()

  # To choose the text 
  soup_text = body.select('div')[0]
```

**I have the following questions**

1. How can I choose the author id?
2. To choose the text should I use 'div' or 'ab'?
3. How can I choose the title of a text?

Thank you so much for you help!

Here you are the text

```
<div author_id="0093" work_id="006" work_short="Metaph">
<ab l0="0093" l1="006" l2="Metaph" l8="4a" l9="1t">
<lb n="1t"/>
<title>ΘΕΟΦΡΑΣΤΟΥ ΤΩΝ ΜΕΤΑ ΤΑ ΦΥΣΙΚΑ</title>
<lb n="2"/>
Πῶσ ἀφορίσαι δεῖ καὶ ποίοισ τὴν ὑπὲρ τῶν
<lb n="3"/>
πρώτων θεωρίαν; ἡ γὰρ δὴ τῆσ φύσεωσ πολυ‐
<lb n="4"/>
χουστέρα, καὶ ὥσ γε δή τινέσ φασιν, ἀτακτοτέρα,
<lb n="5"/>
```

A valid XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div author_id="0093" work_id="006" work_short="Metaph">
   <ab l0="0093" l1="006" l2="Metaph" l8="4a" l9="1t">
      <lb n="1t" />
      <title>ΘΕΟΦΡΑΣΤΟΥ ΤΩΝ ΜΕΤΑ ΤΑ ΦΥΣΙΚΑ</title>
      <lb n="2" />
      Πῶσ ἀφορίσαι δεῖ καὶ ποίοισ τὴν ὑπὲρ τῶν
      <lb n="3" />
      πρώτων θεωρίαν; ἡ γὰρ δὴ τῆσ φύσεωσ πολυ‐
      <lb n="4" />
      χουστέρα, καὶ ὥσ γε δή τινέσ φασιν, ἀτακτοτέρα,
      <lb n="5" />
   </ab>
</div>
```

Comment: Upload a valid XML / HTML doc as **text**

Comment: @mzjn I edited my post, please check it.

Comment: @balderman I uploaded it.

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos - is that the content of the file - it looks like HTML snippet? Dont you have a full doc? I have added a valid snippet to the post. Can we work with that doc?

Comment: @balderman I have exectly what I uploaded. There isn't this line that you uploaded it.

Comment: About 2 - what is the  text you are looking for? Between the `lb` ?

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos I assumed you are looking in the text between `lb`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way.

- Since you need `author_id`, select the `<div>`. As `author_id` is an attribute of  tag, you can extract it like this

  ```
  d = soup.find('div')
  author_id = d['author_id']
  ```
- For title, select the `<title>` tag using `.find()` and print it's text

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div author_id="0093" work_id="006" work_short="Metaph">
   <ab l0="0093" l1="006" l2="Metaph" l8="4a" l9="1t">
      <lb n="1t" />
      <title>ΘΕΟΦΡΑΣΤΟΥ ΤΩΝ ΜΕΤΑ ΤΑ ΦΥΣΙΚΑ</title>
      <lb n="2" />
      Πῶσ ἀφορίσαι δεῖ καὶ ποίοισ τὴν ὑπὲρ τῶν
      <lb n="3" />
      πρώτων θεωρίαν; ἡ γὰρ δὴ τῆσ φύσεωσ πολυ‐
      <lb n="4" />
      χουστέρα, καὶ ὥσ γε δή τινέσ φασιν, ἀτακτοτέρα,
      <lb n="5" />
   </ab>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')
d = soup.find('div')
author_id = d['author_id']
title = d.find('title').text

txt = ' '.join(list(d.ab.stripped_strings)[1:])

print(f'Author_ID: {author_id}\nTitle: {title}\nText: {txt}')
```

```
Author_ID: 0093
Title: ΘΕΟΦΡΑΣΤΟΥ ΤΩΝ ΜΕΤΑ ΤΑ ΦΥΣΙΚΑ
Text: Πῶσ ἀφορίσαι δεῖ καὶ ποίοισ τὴν ὑπὲρ τῶν πρώτων θεωρίαν; ἡ γὰρ δὴ τῆσ φύσεωσ πολυ‐ χουστέρα, καὶ ὥσ γε δή τινέσ φασιν, ἀτακτοτέρα,
```

Comment: is it possible to have a string in non list format?

Comment: You can use ```.join()``` to get a complete string rather than a list of strings. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so so much! One more question to understand the way of your thinking, why we need 'ab' in 'txt = ' '.join(list(d.ab.stripped_strings)[1:])'? If I use just 'txt = ' '.join(list(d.stripped_strings)[1:])' I have the same output.

Comment: Both will work since ```<ab>``` is the only child of ```<div>``` . But if ```<div>``` has any other child then ```list(d.stripped_strings)``` will give different result. In the code I'm specifically selecting the child ```<ab>``` for this reason.

Comment: @Ran, without specifing the child the code gives us the texts from all the childs as I can see, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString

html = '''<div author_id="0093" work_id="006" work_short="Metaph">
<ab l0="0093" l1="006" l2="Metaph" l8="4a" l9="1t">
<lb n="1t"/>
<title>ΘΕΟΦΡΑΣΤΟΥ ΤΩΝ ΜΕΤΑ ΤΑ ΦΥΣΙΚΑ</title>
<lb n="2"/>
Πῶσ ἀφορίσαι δεῖ καὶ ποίοισ τὴν ὑπὲρ τῶν
<lb n="3"/>
πρώτων θεωρίαν; ἡ γὰρ δὴ τῆσ φύσεωσ πολυ‐
<lb n="4"/>
χουστέρα, καὶ ὥσ γε δή τινέσ φασιν, ἀτακτοτέρα,
<lb n="5"/>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

author_id = soup.div.attrs['author_id']
print('------------------')
print(f'author_id: {author_id}')
print('------------------')
title = soup.div.title.text
print(f'title: {title}')
print('------------------')
text = []
for child in soup.div.ab.children:
    if isinstance(child,NavigableString):
      if child.text.strip():
        text.append(child.text.strip())
print(f'text: {text}')
```

output

```
------------------
author_id: 0093
------------------
title: ΘΕΟΦΡΑΣΤΟΥ ΤΩΝ ΜΕΤΑ ΤΑ ΦΥΣΙΚΑ
------------------
text: ['Πῶσ ἀφορίσαι δεῖ καὶ ποίοισ τὴν ὑπὲρ τῶν', 'πρώτων θεωρίαν; ἡ γὰρ δὴ τῆσ φύσεωσ πολυ‐', 'χουστέρα, καὶ ὥσ γε δή τινέσ φασιν, ἀτακτοτέρα,']
```

Comment: Actually I have the following error 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Did you copy and paste my code? It worked and tested..

Comment: yeah I did it. Exactly copy paste

Comment: Let me check thst

Comment: I checked it again. Seems to work fine. See https://replit.com/@avishaybalderman/ColorfulRequiredGenerics#main.py